Laravel 11 - implementing @checked directive in Blade components
I have been using a blade checkbox component with great success with the last few versions of Laravel. Recently I learned of the @checked and @selected blade directives. I love the simplicity of writing a statement that only needs to evaluate to true or false.
I am struggling to successfully implement this in my blade component with Laravel 11. As of how, to use @checked, I switch back to using a generic input.
<x-checkbox name="paid" label="Paid" 
    checked> //works
</x-checkbox>

<x-checkbox name="paid" label="Paid" 
    @checked($ledger_row->paid == 1)> //fails
</x-checkbox>

@props([ 'checked'=>false, 'name' => '', 'label' => '', 'disabled'=>false,])

    <label class="inline-flex items-center mt-2">
        <input
            {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-green_500 rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-green-300 focus:ring focus:ring-green-200 focus:ring-opacity-50']) }}
            name="{{ $name }}"
            id="{{ $name }}"
            type="checkbox"  
            {{$checked?'checked':null}}
            {{$disabled?'disabled':null}}
        >
        <span class="ml-2 text-bf_brown text-sm font-medium">{{ $label }}</span>
    </label>

@error($name)
<div class="text-red-600 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror

